# A constructor that only accepts named parameters matching its properties

Tags: python, python-2.7, constructor

I'd like to have a class in Python 2.7 where:

1. I can pass to the constructor one or more named parameters, which initialize their corresponding properties
2. If any of those named parameters is not a specified property of the class, an exception is raised
3. Each property for which there is no named parameter passed at construction has a value of `None`

I have something working, but I suspect there must be an easier and/or more pythonic way - is there?

```
class Foo:
   bar = None
   baz = None
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):

      for k in kwargs:
         getattr(self, k)

      vars(self).update(kwargs)
```

then I can do

```
>>> f = Foo(bar = 3)
>>> f.bar
3
>>> not f.baz
True
```

and if I do

```
>>> f = Foo(bar = 3, bazz = 5) # 'bazz' is a typo
```

..then an Exception is raised, which is what I want, because it caught the 'bazz' typo.

So it seems I have something working, but I don't know what I don't know, so: is there a better /easier / more pythonic way?

Comment: use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) ?

Comment: @Ryan Haining I was initially going to use a namedtuple, but if I understand right, it requires all the properties to be passed in the constructor, and I want to be able to optionally omit some. Also, I may want to add methods to the class later, so for future proofing a namedtuple isnt ideal.

Comment: You can subclass a named tuple.

Comment: Are you sure you want `foo` and `baz` to be class attributes?

Comment: @chepner like this? http://mmabrouk.github.io/python/2014/05/23/namedtuples-with-default-optional-arguments/  The thing with that is that it's not very DRY, since 'color' is repeated. Is there a way to do it w/o repeating the property names? FWI, I'm not too concerned by the performance cost of a class vs a namedtuple

Comment: A named tuple is just a class; I was just pointing out that you *can* subclass  one to add methods. I agree it's not a good solution if you want optional parameters.

Comment: @jme that's a good question. I dont fully understand the consequences of them being class attributes. Does it stop me setting the `baz` value of an instance of Foo, w/o other affects? . I.e. I can do `f = Foo()`  `f.baz = 42` w/o affecting any class attributes - right? is there a solution that doesnt require  class attributes?

Comment: @chepner got it - thanks. sorry, i misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your class should explicitly extend `object` in Python 2.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for arg in ["bar", "baz"]
            value = kwargs.pop(arg, None)
            setattr(self, arg, value)

        if kwargs:
            invalid_args = ", ".join(kwargs)
            raise ValueError("Invalid keyword argument(s): %s" % (invalid_args,)
```

In `__init__`, simply use `pop` to retrieve the expected keyword arguments and remove them from the dict. If any arguments remain, raise an error indicating which extra arguments were found.

---

Unless you have a lot of variables to set, I find it more readable to skip the loop and set each variable individually.

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.bar = kwargs.pop("bar", None)
    self.baz = kwargs.pop("baz", None)
    if kwargs:
        ...
```

Comment: thanks - this looks better. Any comment on whether doing this is a good/bad idea and/or pythonic? I ask because my (uneducated) assumption is that this would be a common requirement, so there would be a 'built-in' solution, or at the very least a well documented one. Yet it seems there is not, which makes me question that assumption, and then question the validity of my need. Can you shed any light on that? To put it another way, which of the 3 listed requirements is unusual?

Comment: #2 is the most unusual, but only in the sense that the language doesn't have any notion of a required set of attributes for a class instance.